# Kinect - Map color and infrared 2D coordinates

Tags: kinect, infrared

Is there an easy way to convert the coordinates of a point from a color frame to an infrared in Kinect V2?

Infrareds seem to be trimmed on both sides (on the X axis).

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your infrared frame seems to be trimmed on both sides of the X axis is because of [this](http://www.smeenk.com/webgl/kinectfovexplorer.html). Due to the frames not being captured of equal size, as you can see in the url, the infrared frame is slightly smaller than colour frames

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I see what you mean ! I believe I have to convert my ColorSpacePoint to a DepthSpacePoint to correlate both the color and infrared frame coordinates. Do you know how I could do that? I haven't seen any methods related in the `CoordinateMapper`.

Comment: @Max I am currently working on gestures so i am not too familiar with the CoordinateMapper. Would love to help but no knowledge about that, Sorry:(